# How to preserve and reverse a string?

Tags: python, python-3.x

> Write a function that accepts a string of words separated by spaces
>   consisting of alphabetic characters and returns a string such that
>   each word in the input string is reversed while the order of the words
>   in the input string is preserved. Capitalization does matter here. The
>   length of the input string must be equal to the length of the output
>   string i.e. there should be no trailing or leading spaces in your
>   output string. For example if:
>
> input_string   = “this is a sample test”
>
> then the function should return a string such as:
>
> "siht si a elpmas tset"

**This is my code:**

```
def preserve_and_reverse (input_str):
    list = input_str.split()
    print (list)
    reverse_character = ""
    for i in range (0, len(input_str)):
        split_list = list[0:(i + 1)]
        print (split_list) 
        for j in split_list_advance:
            reverse_character = reverse_character + split_list[j]
        output_str = output_str.append(reverse_character)
    output = output_str.replace("", " ")
    print (output)

#Main Program
input_str = input("Enter a string: ")
result = preserve_and_reverse (input_str)
print (result)
```

I am not getting anywhere with the code. Should I try a different approach like traverse each character and when I encounter a white-space just slice the string and then perform a reverse? 
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Get rid of the input and hard code a string value, e.g. `input_str = 'mary had a little lamb'`. It'll make the testing cycle quicker.

Comment: What is `split_list_advance`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this will do (step-by-step):

```
input_string = "this is a sample test"
words = input_string.split()
nwords = []
for i in words:
    rword = ""
    for c in reversed(word):
        rword += c
    nwords.append(rword)
output_string = " ".join(nwords)    
print(output_string)
```

**Result:**

```
siht si a elpmas tset
```

**Step by step explanation:**

1. You split your input text into list of string:

   ```
    words = input_string.split()
   ```
2. You iterate over the `words`

   ```
    for word in words):
   ```
3. For each `word`, you prepare a reversed word `rword` and build up the reversed word by adding up character from the old word but reversed:

   ```
    rword = ""
    for c in reversed(word):
        rword += c
    nwords.append(rword)
   ```
4. you rejoin the reversed words - but in order and print it:

   ```
    output_string = " ".join(nwords)    
    print(output_string)
   ```

Or, more simply:

```
input_string = "this is a sample test"
words = input_string.split()
output_string = ""
for word in words:
    for c in reversed(word):
        output_string += c
    output_string += " "
print(output_string)
```

Comment: Why not say `for word in words:`?

Comment: Playing with this, would `re.split(r'\b'`, input_string)` be more accurate?

Comment: What is reversed(word) doing?

Comment: it reverse the word. Or to be precise, it creates an effect such that when the word is iterated (like what I did by taking the character one by one), it will go the reverse way...

Comment: Okay but reverse doesn't work on split() list right?

Comment: "doesn't work on `split()`" it does work actually... but after you split, you iteration element becomes the word. Thus, reversing a list will result in reversing the order of the list, which you want to avoid. {"I", "am", "here"} becomes {"here", "am", "I"}

Comment: @KaranThakkar and that's the reason why I apply it per word instead of to the whole list

Comment: @KaranThakkar does my explanation help you?

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. I think I understand the concept better now. It'll take time though.

Comment: @KaranThakkar glad that I can be of any help. :) yes, all the best for your learning.

Answer (score 6):

`Split` over spaces, reverse each string through `map` with `[::-1]` then `join` them back with 
 `' '.join`

```
>>> s = 'this is a sample test'
>>> 
>>> ' '.join(map(lambda s:s[::-1], s.split()))
'siht si a elpmas tset'
```

Answer (score 2):

This is how I would have done it:

```
def preserve_and_reverse(input_str):

    # Split the String into an Array
    list_ = input_str.split(" ")

    return_str = ""

    # For Each String in the Array
    for item in list_:

        # Add Reversed String to Return String
        return_str += item[::-1] + " "

    # Return String without leading/trailing spaces
    return return_str.strip()

# Main Program
string_input = input("Enter a string: ")
result = preserve_and_reverse(string_input.strip())
print(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

`word[::-1]` reverses the order of the string variable named `word` which is obtained by iterating through each split word in the sentence.

```
>>> ' '.join(word[::-1] for word in input_string.split())
'siht si a elpmas tset'
```

Step by step:

```
>>> input_string.split()
['this', 'is', 'a', 'sample', 'test']

>>> [word[::-1] for word in input_string.split()]
['siht', 'si', 'a', 'elpmas', 'tset']

>>> ' '.join(word[::-1] for word in input_string.split())
'siht si a elpmas tset'
```

Answer (score 0):

All of the other answers so far ignore what happens when extra spaces are between words or at either end of the input string. Please test your code to verify that is works properly. The `main` function provided below has a few tests that you may want to use to verify your function is working properly, and you may want to add more tests if you find that your code is not behaving correctly:

```
def main():
    print('Running test 1 ...')
    text = 'this is a sample test'
    par = preserve_and_reverse(text)
    assert par == 'siht si a elpmas tset'
    print('Running test 2 ...')
    text = 'This is a sample TEST'
    par = preserve_and_reverse(text)
    assert par == 'sihT si a elpmas TSET'
    print('Running test 3 ...')
    text = 'This string  has   some    extra     spaces'
    par = preserve_and_reverse(text)
    assert par == 'sihT gnirts  sah   emos    artxe     secaps'
    print('Running test 4 ...')
    text = ' check  spaces   at    string     ends      '
    par = preserve_and_reverse(text)
    assert par == ' kcehc  secaps   ta    gnirts     sdne      '
    print('Done!')


def preserve_and_reverse(text):
    return ' '.join(word[::-1] for word in text.split(' '))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score -1):

```py
def sample(string):
    list=[]
    string1=string.split()
    for i in string1:
        list.append(i[::-1])
    print(" ".join(list))

if __name__=="__main__":
    input=input("Enter string: ")
    sample(input)
```

Comment: Please add some details as to why this  is a good solution and how it works, and helps solve the problem. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer